# Which api endpoint to use

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

So there are two endpoints: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists
and
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-list-users-playlists

one is based on the user id and one is based on the current user but what do they mean by the current user

Comment: Is there a problem using [Get User's Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-list-users-playlists)?

Comment: But what his the difference between that and this endpoint: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists here it says it gets the playlists for the "current user" but what does that mean

Answer (score 1):

The API request to get a list of the playlists owned by the current Spotify user is:

```
GET /me/playlists
```

This API is fully documented at [get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists).

The API request to get a list of the playlists owned or followed by a specific Spotify user is:

```
GET /users/{user_id}/playlists
```

This API is fully documented at [get-list-users-playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-list-users-playlists).

You would use the latter API to retrieve playlists for other users, for example Spotify friends or other users that have public playlists.

Comment: What is this current Spotify user based on? Is it authenticating with Spotify?

Comment: The user that authorized the client app to use the Spotify API to access their data. Example client project [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/howtos/web-app-profile).

Comment: So is "current user" always going to be referring to the Spotify user that you got the access token from?